# Wordpress: sort custom post type posts

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, custom-post-type

So I have a custom post type called members.
Here members are added via advanced custom fields.

The members I display in a template page.

now I want them sorted under ABC. somewhat like this:
[image: example for the users] 
"In the picture, I made only the first few letters visible for privacy reasons."

and I want it so if there is no user with a specific letter it won't show the letter above.
like if there were no users with the letter **B** it would just go from **A** to **C**

I'm not really good with PHP but I made like a small beginning to an if statement:

```
<?php
$current_character = '';
while (loop) {
    $first_character = code to get first character out of name;
    if ($current_character != $first_character) {
        echo $first_character;

        $current_character = $first_character;
    }
    echo $name;
}
?>
```

I know this is 100% not gonna work yet. but it might be useful for u guys to help me :D

The code I have for displaying my members on the template page is:

```
$member_type = (isset($member_type) ? $member_type : 'seb');
$post_type = $member_type == 'seb' ? array('companies', 'members') : 'companies';
// prepare arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'                 => 'members',
    'orderby'                   => 'metavalue',
    'meta_key'                  => 'contactperson',
    'order'                     => 'ASC',
    'post_status'               => 'publish',
);

// create a query based on arguments
$query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($query->have_posts()):
    $query->the_post();
```

plus I have:

```
<section>
    <p>
        <?php echo (get_field('title') ? get_field('title') . ' ' : '') ?>
        <?php the_field('contactperson') ?>
    </p>
</section>
```

the users are sorted and displayed by contactperson

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem now? If it's only about building those arrays, you should maybe strip out all the WP stuff from your questions. If it's about the WP part, clarify that. :-)

Comment: well, in the end, it needs to look like the picture. so it's about the arrays yeah.
I added the WordPress stuff to clarify.

Comment: How are these sections of code related to each other? Where does this get values ? `while (loop)`